# No result defined for and result success

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm new to struts 2 and I keep getting this error message 'No result defined for action com.jjpeople.action.HelloAction and result success' while I think I have properly refrenced it.What might be the problem?

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <package name="tutiworks" extends="struts-default">  
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>       
        <action name="hello" class="com.jjpeople.action.HelloAction" method="execute">
                <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>   
    </package>
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic Struts 2 Application - Welcome</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome To Struts 2!</h1>
        <p><a href="<s:url action='hello'/>">Hello World</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Action class**

```
package com.jjpeople.action;

import com.jjpeople.model.Hello;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Hello hello;

    public String execute() throws Exception 
    {
        hello = new Hello();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public Hello getMessage() 
    {
        return hello;
    }
    public void setMessage(Hello hello) 
    {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use **[Config Browser Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/config-browser-plugin.html)** to check **Struts2's** action mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file

```
<action name="hello" class="com.jjpeople.action.HelloAction" method="execute">                 <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>         </action>
```

result name is "success",But in your Action class you returnd "SICCESS" variable.So please check the SUCCESS variable value.

Answer (score 0):

The result is struts.xml and Action didn't equals.So returned the exception you didn't be defined.